# PowerBI: Count unique sub-ID's per ID and per period in a new column

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am running into an issue with defining a new column and I hope you can help me. I would like to count the distinct values of one column (sub-ID) with filters on 2 axis; period and ID. I would like to do this for every row and post the result as a new column.  I have data structured at sub-ID level over time. ID's are also stated. My data looks like this:

| Period | ID | Sub-ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 202101 | 123000 | 01 |
| 202101 | 123000 | 02 |
| 202101 | 123000 | 03 |
| 202102 | 123000 | 01 |
| 202102 | 123000 | 02 |
| 202102 | 123000 | 03 |
| 202101 | 456000 | 01 |
| 202101 | 456000 | 02 |
| 202102 | 456000 | 01 |
| 202102 | 456000 | 02 |

Here I would like to add a column per row that states how many sub-ID's belong to an ID for that particular Period. So with the new column my data should look like this:

| Period | ID | Sub-ID | Number of sub-ID's |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 202101 | 123000 | 01 | 3 |
| 202101 | 123000 | 02 | 3 |
| 202101 | 123000 | 03 | 3 |
| 202102 | 123000 | 01 | 3 |
| 202102 | 123000 | 02 | 3 |
| 202102 | 123000 | 03 | 3 |
| 202101 | 456000 | 01 | 2 |
| 202101 | 456000 | 02 | 2 |
| 202102 | 456000 | 01 | 2 |
| 202102 | 456000 | 02 | 2 |

I would share code of what I tried but I don't feel confident I have gotten sufficiently close to the desired result with previous tries. I tried working with the CALCULATE function but I can not get the filtering right on both ID and Period. I hope someone can assist me, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add a column to your dataset you can add this calculated column, this is useful if you want to use the results as a slicer or dimension:

```
Number of Sub IDs = 
CALCULATE ( 
    COUNTROWS ( 'Table' ) , 
    ALLEXCEPT (
        'Table' , 
        'Table'[Period],
        'Table'[ID]
    )
)
```

You can use the same code in a **measure** to show this in a table visual without using up space in your data model:

[image]

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks a lot! Excuse me for not voting on your answer as my vote does not count due to my low reputation (first ever question). I am not sure how it works though. How should I view the ALLEXCEPT function in this regard? Thanks again for answering my question.

Comment: For a short explanation: The `ALLEXCEPT` function gives you all the rows of your specified table, except those rows affected by filter context on the columns you specify.  You can also use different approaches, see this article by SQLBI suggesting use of `ALL` in conjunction with `VALUES` , which is better in some cases: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/using-allexcept-versus-all-and-values/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by SUMMARIZE function in DAX

```
Table = SUMMARIZE(Data, Data[Period], Data[ID], Data[Sub-ID], "Distinct Count", CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(DISTINCT(Data[Sub-ID])), ALL(Data[Sub-ID])))
```

[image]

Comment: It would seem a bit extreme to add a whole new table to the datamodel instead of just adding a column or, in this case, a measure.

Comment: I tried this solution. My dataset has 1.3 million rows and this solution seems to have crashed Power BI. Thank you for your input. I would vote on your answer but due to my low reputation score stackoverflow does not allow it. The answer of Marcus fortunately solved the issue.